# On Error GoTo only working once for analyzing input box value

Tags: vba, excel, onerror

I have a spreadsheet that tracks the time various files are sent.  For each file I have an input box that asks for the time the file sent, and there are a few other options that can be put in that input box.

If the person does not enter a valid entry, I would like to send them back to the input box so they can try again.

This is my code, which works for the first error, but if someone enters the wrong value a second time, they just get the standard 'Type Mismatch' error.  I am creating this for people who don't have any knowledge of VBA and would like to make it as easy as possible.

There are multiple instances of the following code, each for a different file time.  Thanks in advance!

```
CFP:
If Err Then MsgBox Error & " Invalid value.  Please enter only 'blank', 'holiday', 'skip' or time value."
Err.Clear
tm = UCase(Application.InputBox("What time was the CFP file sent?"))

On Error GoTo CFP
If tm = "BLANK" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Blank"
ElseIf tm = "HOLIDAY" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = "Holiday"
ElseIf tm = "SKIP" Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "Skipped"
Else
    ActiveCell.Value = TimeValue(tm)
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error handlers go *below* the procedure they're handling errors for:

```
Public Sub DoSomething
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'code here

Cleanup:
    'cleanup code here
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    'error-handling code here
    Resume Cleanup
End Sub
```

What's happening is that once the first error is raised, *because the error handler label is at the top*, instead of jumping *down* into the error handler, the code jumps *up* back to the top, and VBA understands the rest of the procedure to be the error-handling subroutine... which never returns to the actual procedure body, because it *is* the procedure's body.

You're using the wrong control flow structure for the job, see [@Matteo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29951756/1188513) for what you need.

Comment: This explains perfectly your problem.

Comment: Thank you both!!  I ended up using the error handler, but since I have to do the input box step repeatedly for different files, I decided to pass the name of each file to sub(fileName).  Then the time for that file is entered in an input box and then run through an error handler.  Thanks Again!

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using the error handler, I would use a `Loop` that would break only when the condition is met. For example:

*Ask the first time:*

```
tm = UCase(Application.InputBox("What time was the CFP file sent?"))
Dim inputOK As Boolean
```

*Keep on asking until the user enters wrong values:*

```
inputOK = checkMyInput(tm) '<-- is the input "tm" ok or not?
Do While inputOK = False '<-- if it's not ok, keep on asking
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid input"
    tm = UCase(Application.InputBox("What time was the CFP file sent?"))   
    inputOK = checkMyInput(tm) '<-- and checking it again...
Loop
```

where `checkMyInput(tm)` would be a custom function returning `True` or `False` if your input is ok or not:

```
Function checkMyInput(ByVal tm As Variant) As Boolean
    If tm ="BLANK" Or tm = "HOLIDAY" Or tm = "SKIP" Or IsDate(tm) Then
        checkMyInput = True
    Else
        checkMyInput = False
    End If
End Function
```